# pass variable in javascript to sql server using ajax

Tags: php, javascript, sql, google-maps

I want to do a google map which allows people to click on the map and saves the point as starting point or ending point. After clicking a point, an infowindow will be seen. I changed the google map coordinate into my own defined coordinate. And I have made a database with buildings in the coordinate.
That is, database like this
(x Y Building)(1, 2, Tower 1)(1, 3, Tower 2)

I want to pass coordinate to search in the sql database and return back the building. And show the building name in a textfield. However, it seems the return is not succeed. Please help me. I have searched in the internet a long long time.

storelatlng.php

```
require_once("Connections/fees0_7548734_cumap.php");
$x = $_GET['x'];
$y = $_GET['y'];
$data = mysql_query("SELECT Bname FROM Coordinate WHERE X=2 AND Y=58") or die(mysql_error());
$info = mysql_fetch_array($data);
$Bname = $info['Bname'];
echo $Bname;
```

mapfunction.php

```
var map;
var Bname="";
function storelatlng(){
   var y = document.getElementById("Latitude").value;
   var x = document.getElementById("Longitude").value

   var getVars = "?y="+y+"&x="+x;

   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       var request=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
       var request=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   request.open('GET','storelatlng.php'+getVars,true);
   request.onreadystatechange = function(){
       if(request.readyState == 4){
          var xmlDoc = request.responseText;
          document.getElementById("frmLat").value = xmlDoc;
       }
   }
   request.send(null);
   return false;

}
function initialize() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {

    map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(22.419161, 114.207559), 17);
    GEvent.addListener(map,"click",
        function(overlay,latlng){
            var setLat = latlng.lat();
            var setLon = latlng.lng();
            setLat = Math.floor((Math.floor(setLat*100000)-2241187)/20); 
            setLon = Math.floor((Math.floor(setLon*100000)-11420020)/20 );
            //y
            document.getElementById("frmLat").value = setLat;
            //x
            document.getElementById("frmLon").value = setLon;
            var inputForm = document.createElement("form");
            inputForm.setAttribute("action","");
            inputForm.onsubmit = function(){storelatlng();
            return false;
            };
    inputForm.innerHTML = '<fieldset style = "width:200px;">'
        + '<legend> Mark Point </legend>'
        + 'Please choose it '+Bname+' your starting or ending point.'+'<p></p>'
        +  '<label><input type="radio" name="choice" value="0" id="choice_s" />Start</label>'
        +  '<label><input type="radio" name="choice" value="1" id="choice_e" />End</label>'
        + '<input type="submit" value="Save"/>'
        + '<input type="hidden" id="Longtitude" value="'+setLon+'"/>'
        + '<input type="hidden" id="Latitude" value="'+setLat+'"/>';

    map.openInfoWindow(latlng,inputForm);
        });
<?php
```

Comment: Have you traced where the problem is occurring? Is `storelatlng.php` receiving valid lat/lng? Also, is there a reason why you are hardcoding `X=2 and Y=58` in `storelatlng.php`?

Answer (score 0):

At a bare minimum, make sure your functions and function calls are done correctly. `GEvent.addListener` is missing a closing paren (there's a semicolon after the anonymous function, which means that  `GEvent.addListener` is over) and there is an extra paren at the end of your code sample. Initialize also looks like it is missing a brace.